# How to quickly test if a class is serializable in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, serializable

For an object to be serializable in Java, one has to make sure that its own class and other classes that it uses internally are all serializable. Is there a easy way in Eclipse to automate this tedious check? Thanks.

Comment: Generally, it's not possible. You can only know at runtime. Let's say your class contains a single field of type Object. If this field is an instance of Integer, the object is serializable. If it's an instance of Socket, it's not.

Comment: Makes sense. It's kind of having Eclipse finding all references of a certain class, which would probably not identify those references through Java Reflection. Nevertheless, it would be still very helpful to identify those explicitly dependent classes to avoid repeated trials and errors.